# Translate title in a config file

Tags: localisation, configuration

I have a label for my custom payment method in the config.xml file. It looks like this:

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <cashpayment translate="title" module="paygate">
            <active>1</active>
            <model>payments/cash</model>
            <order_status>1</order_status>
            <title>Cash Payment</title>
        </cashpayment>
    </payment>
</default>
```

Unfortunately, despite 'translate' parameter the output in the front end is still 'Cash Payment'. I've updated translation file, flushed the cache but it didn't help. 
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated :)?

Answer (score 2):

This will try to translate using `Mage::helper('paygate')->__('Cash Payment')`.

`paygate` is the alias of `Mage_Paygate`, so your translation must be defined either

1. in `Mage_Paygate.csv`
2. in the `translate.csv` of your theme as `"Mage_Paygate::Cash Payment","Your translation here"`
3. in the database, using inline translation

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your front end is set to the correct locale which you made the translations.
   System->Configuration. Change Current Configuration Scope to the Correct Front End Store.  Under General Tab->Locale Options.
2. Systems->Cache Management Refresh Magento Cache for all Cache Types, Flush Magento Cache & Flush Cache Storage.